# How do I overwrite existing google sheet with similar name and data using google script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have done a bit of googling/ research and the code below is the closest to what I wanted to accomplish.

I have  a spreadsheet with data and what the code does is to look at column **A** of the the source sheet and creates new sheets with the name in the that column and then carries all row data that matches that name to the new sheet.

This code works perfectly fine, I will appreciate help to modify it such that:

- Instead of saying **"Sheet already exists"** it should just overwrite the sheet with similar name.
- While copying matching values, It should include  first row (**A1**, The title row)

  ```
  function backUP() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var templateSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
      var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Source")
      var getNames = [...new Set(sheet1.getRange("A2:A").getValues().filter(String).toString().split(","))];

  for (var i = 0; i < getNames.length; i++) {
      var copy = ss.getSheetByName(getNames[i]);
      if (copy) {
          Logger.log("Sheet already exists");
      } else {


          var rowIndexes = sheet1.getRange("A:A").getValues()
              .map((value, index) => [value[0], (index + 1)])
              .filter(value => value[0] === getNames[i]);
          var namedSheet = ss.insertSheet(getNames[i]);
          rowIndexes.map(index => {
              var rowValues = sheet1.getRange(index[1], 1, 1, sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
              namedSheet.appendRow(rowValues[0]);
          });


          ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(getNames[i]));
          ss.moveActiveSheet(ss.getNumSheets());
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete a sheet/tab in a Google spreadsheet pragmatically using GAS/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61303139/how-do-i-delete-a-sheet-tab-in-a-google-spreadsheet-pragmatically-using-gas-java)

Comment: @TheMaster   It does. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
 if (copy) { 

 ss.deleteSheet(copy)

 }
```